# Run-time compile C# code in Portable Class Library (PCL)

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, runtime-compilation

I am writing a [PCL (Portable Class Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.100).aspx) in C#.

I was wondering **how can I compile a C# code (given as `string`) and run it**.

Already tried to use `CSharpCodeProvider` and `CodeDomProvider` but none of them is available in PCL and I didn't find NuGet package which contains them. Proable there is something I am missing.

Comment: The section ``Assemblies The following assemblies are available within a Portable Class Library project: `` of the page you provide a link for does not list the assemblies you need. That means... ;)

Comment: It doesn't mean that there is no NuGet package that will provide functionality for compiling C# code :)

Comment: For what platforms are you intending to write it for? Maybe you can just put interface in PCL and then make platform-specific implementation for each targeted platform?

Comment: UWP and .NET Core